# Is there an R function for merging multiple data frames vertically by rows?

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, rows

I wanted to know if there's an R function that appends the rows of multiple data frames into a single data frame, vertically. The columns of my datasets are different and have different names, so I can't use rbind(). I have tried bind_rows() and smartbind() but still got the output in a horizontal fashion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is less obvious to work out how to do than I thought: if you try

```r
rbind(unname(x), unname(y))
```

then R throws an error.

The easiest way I found was to convert the data.frames into matrices before binding them:

```r
as.data.frame(rbind(as.matrix(x), as.matrix(y)))
```

The resulting data.frame has the same column names as the first data.frame given, in this case `x`. You still need the data.frames to have the same number of columns, however.

Outside of base R, the `data.table` package has a version of `rbind` that can ignore names when binding:

```r
library(data.table)
rbind(as.data.table(x), as.data.table(y), use.names = FALSE)
```

However, this will return a `data.table` rather than a `data.frame`, so you'll probably want to convert it back afterwards.